# While loop wont end with more than one exception

Tags: c++

I'm probably missing something very basic but I've searched and haven't found anything similar. The program should end when the variable num1 gets to 10 however it waits for num2 to get to 10 too. I'm pretty sure I'm using the or operator correctly.

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        int num1 = 5;
        int num2 = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        do{
            counter++;
            num1++;
            num2++;
            cout << counter << "  " << num1 << "   " << num2 << endl;
        } while (num1 <= 10 || num2 <= 10);

    }
```

Comment: _I'm pretty sure I'm using the or operator correctly._ No you're not, proof is your program is not behaving like you think it would.

Comment: Try using `&&` and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your while statement says, "continue as long as either num1 or num2 are less than or equal to ten".  The statement is a boolean expression "keep going while this is true".  If you replace the || (or) with && (and) then you will be saying to continue while both variables are less than or equal to ten.

Comment: It worked, but I still don't understand exactly how?  Isn't && supposed to mean "do both" while or means "only have to do one as long as something is done?"

Comment: The **while** in `do { ... } while()` or `while() { ... }` is "while this statement is true".  && doesn't mean "do both" it means "and".  So, read in (mostly) English, the statement now reads "do { this stuff } while (num1 is less than or equal to 10) and (num2 is less than or equal to 10)".  Once either one of those things is false, then the statement is no longer true, and the loop ends.

Answer (score 4):

```
F or F = F            F or T = T        T or F = T    T or T = T
```

So in your case even first comparison is false when num1 is greater than 10, the second comparison makes the whole expression true

Answer (score 3):

Use the && operator in place of the || operator.

&& is the Boolean "and" operator, and will provide the functionality you desire.

Answer (score 2):

Not is hard; the human brain doesn't deal well with it.

You want to stop the loop when

```
num1 > 10 || num2 > 10
```

However, in a while loop you have to say when the loop should continue - which is not (loop should stop).

Now !(a || b) == !a && !b. (That's the law - de Morgan's law.)

So you want

```
while (!(num1 > 10 || num2 > 10))
```

Which is

```
while (!(num1 > 10) && !(num2 > 10))
```

Which is

```
while (num1 <= 10 && num2 <= 10)
```